# SelectionChanged Event Not Firing When Clicking on Empty Space Inside a Custom Border in a DataGrid Row

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, event-handling, wpf-controls

Here is my DataGridSamplePage.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="SampleWpf.DataGridSamplePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="DataGridSamplePage">
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomDataGridRowStyle"
           TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Background="LightGray"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="20"
                            Margin="0,5,0,5">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                    ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsControl.ItemsPanel}"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                                      Visibility="{TemplateBinding DataGridRow.DetailsVisibility}"
                                                      SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                               SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                               Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid 
              x:Name="MyDataGrid"
              SelectionChanged="MyDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged"
              Margin="20"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Background="Transparent"
              BorderThickness="0"
              FontSize="18"
              RowHeight="80"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
              CanUserSortColumns="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              GridLinesVisibility="None"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              FontWeight="Bold"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              ColumnWidth="Auto"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"
              Height="Auto"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Width="Auto">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="15" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border BorderThickness="0"
                                    Padding="5">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomDataGridRowStyle}" />
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"
                                Binding="{Binding Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PatientId"
                                Binding="{Binding PatientId}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DoctorId"
                                Binding="{Binding DoctorId}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location"
                                Binding="{Binding Location}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Here is my DataGridSamplePage.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class DataGridSamplePage : Page
{
    public DataGridSamplePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Appointment> list = new();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            var appointment = new Appointment
            {
                Id = "i",
                PatientId = $"P{i}",
                DoctorId = $"D{i}",
                Location = $"Location {i}"
            };
            list.Add(appointment);
        }

        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    private void MyDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged fired");
    }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string PatientId { get; set; } 
    public string DoctorId { get; set; }  
    public string Location { get; set; }

}
```

I have a WPF application with a DataGrid that uses a custom row style. This style includes a Border element. My problem is that the DataGrid's SelectionChanged event is not triggered when I click on the empty space within the Border element of a row. The event only fires when I click directly on the text within a cell. I want the event to be triggered when clicking anywhere within the row's Border. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Give the root Border in the DataGridCell style a Transparent backgound.

Comment: @BionicCode did not work

Answer (score 0):

First, you must provide a hit test surface by assigning a background `Brush` to the root `Border` of the `DataGridCell` template. You would usually bind the `Border.Background` to the templated parent's `Background` property.

Second, you must allow the content to stretch to occupy the available cell's space. Currently because `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` is set to `Center` the cell content will only occupy minimal space. So instead set `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` to center and leave `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` set to `Stretch`. Because you are overriding the `ControlTemplate` you must bind `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` to the `ContentPresenter` to allow the content alignment to take effect.

Additionally you must connect other layout attributes to the templated parent. For example, you are setting `Padding` to `20`, but currently this value never propagates to the actual layout/`ControlTemplate` because the `Padding` property is disconnected from the content layout.

The fixed `Style` of the `DataGridCell` could look as follows:

```xml
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
          <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

            <!-- Wire the content to the templated parent's content alignment properties -->
            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Further notes:

- `DataGrid` virtualization is enabled by default. Also set the `DataGrid.EnableColumnVirtualization` and `DataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization` properties instead. `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` has no effect.
- To enable customization by setting attributes locally, you should avoid to hardcode values like Border.Background in your templates (for example in your `CustomDataGridRowStyle`). Instead bind those properties to the templated parent using `{TemplateBinding}` and then set the default value using a `Style.Setter`.
- Always set a collection that implements `INotfyCollectionChanged` (e.g., `ObservableCollection`) to any `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to improve performance (in terms of memory management).
- The nested property path of bindings in your `DataGridRow` on the DataGridCellsPresenter and DataGridDetailsPresenter elements also don't resolve. You are already binding to the `DataGridRow` (which is the templated parent) using `{TemplateBinding}`.
  So the correct property paths are:

```xml
<!--<DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsControl.ItemsPanel}" />-->
<DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" />

<!--<DataGridDetailsPresenter Visibility="{TemplateBinding DataGridRow.DetailsVisibility}" />-->
<DataGridDetailsPresenter Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />
```